# python ImportError without import call

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

Okay, I'm stumped on this one.  I've looked around but I can't find anything and can't figure out how to debug this.  Basically, python is throwing an `ImportError` at a line of code where I'm not importing anything.  I've a decently large module `ICgen` which contains the module `ICgen_settings`.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-105e3826f255>", line 1, in <module>
IC = ICgen.load('IC.p')

File "diskpy/ICgen/ICgen.py", line 339, in load
ICobj.settings.load(input_dict['settings'])

File "diskpy/ICgen/ICgen_settings.py", line 484, in load
tmp_dict = pickle.load(open(settings_filename, 'rb'))

ImportError: No module named ICgen_settings
```

This doesn't make any sense to me.  It clearly has found `ICgen_settings` since it's throwing the error from within it.  Furthermore, I'm not doing an `import` call when it throws the error!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to `pickle.load` the `tmp_dict`, the modules for any of the objects in the incoming data stream need to be loaded.

So yes, you were in fact doing an `import` call when the error was thrown: you were unpickling an object of some type that needed `ICgen_settings`. NB: unpickling code can run arbitrary Python statements. Never unpickle objects you don't trust!

Now, as to why it's "clearly found `ICgen_settings`": No, just being in a file called `ICgen_settings.py` does not mean that the line `import ICgen_settings` will succeed. Whether the import succeeds depends on `sys.path`, which originates from your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. It also depends on the module layout of `ICgen_settings`: normally, it would be an `ICgen_settings` **folder** (not file) containing a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Oh, I see!  I had always treated pickle like a magic black box, but I that all makes sense.  I had restructured my package, so `ICgen_settings` is not on the `PYTHONPATH` anymore.  Thanks!